# Issue validating a youtube url with php

Tags: php, validation, youtube-api

I'm trying to validate a youtube url taken from a form field. The way I have it setup isn't catching any error no matter what I put in. I use getVideoId() to extract the video id from the url which works.

```
    if ($_POST['video_url'] != null && $_POST['video_url'] != 'Youtube URL') {
        $vid_url = $_POST['video_url'];
        $video_id = getVideoId($vid_url);
        $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $video_id);
          if (strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
            $video_url = $vid_url;
          } else {
            $output .= 'This is not an existing youtube video<br/>';
          }
    }
```

The $output is set to null and I check against that before processing the form which works for how I validate other fields so it's just this method that is failing.

Comment: what exactly is the issue ???

Comment: First, print out $headers[0] and see what it actually contains?

Comment: Like I said with this method it doesn't matter what I put in the field. It validates it.

Comment: What is the content of $headers[0] ?

Comment: When I enter a valid youtube video and print $header[0] I get HTTP/1.0 200 OK and when I type in a random string of characters I get the same thing.

Comment: I don't. How about $video_id, what's that?

Comment: It returns the proper video_id if a youtube video is enetered. If a random string nothing is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using cURL

```
$curr_curl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$video_id."?alt=json&v=2";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curr_curl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($code == 200) {
    echo "Valid URL";
}
```

Comment: You can do it with curl, but the issue appears to be that http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ on its own returns 200, so I don't think that addresses the question

Comment: Before making the call you can check if $video_id is empty or not, so that you know you have an URL with a proper ID in it instead of blank which returns 200. Also if you have an invalid ID it would return HTTP 400

Comment: This is giving me unreliable results and I can't figure out why. Sometimes it validates a video and sometimes it doesn't. And If the form is refreshed it never validates. Here is the whole function I use to validate my form. http://pastebin.com/jD0Y1j2d

Answer (score 0):

If there is no valid video id, then $video_id is blank.
If you try:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/');
echo $headers[0];
```

you'll see that it returns a 200.

```
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SOMETHINGINVALID');
echo $headers[0];
```

returns a 4xx of some description.

You'll need to trap both cases:

```
if ($_POST['video_url'] != null && $_POST['video_url'] != 'Youtube URL') {
    $vid_url = $_POST['video_url'];
    $video_id = getVideoId($vid_url);
    if ($video_id) {
        $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $video_id);
        if (strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
            $video_url = $vid_url;
          } else {
              $output .= 'This is not an existing youtube video<br/>';
          }
    } else {
          $output .= 'This is not an existing youtube video<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Now no matter what I put in it doesn't validate. I get a 403 instead of 200 for valid videos.

Comment: I print both the video_id and $header[0] after $headers is set. I get the correct $video_id and the HTTP/1.0 403 ForbiddenPlease which makes no sense.

Comment: you previously indicated that you always got 200, what have you changed?

Comment: It's just completely inconsistent. Sometimes a validates a video and others it doesn't. Can't figure out why at all but here's my entire function I use to process the form. http://pastebin.com/snBj3QTR I don't get it.

Comment: That should work provided getVideoId always returns either a valid video id or a falsy value (like an empty string). Can you please put in some debugging like printing $video_id at each stage to see if you notice what it is when the validation is not correct?

Comment: The id is always correct. I tested it a lot of times. I use a jquery to get the thumb of the video and show it when the user enters the url into the input. So even when it grabs the correct thumb, the php doesn't always validate the url. There is some kind of glitch. I'm having the same issue with the curl example above.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in a php script used to get emails from a gmail account  I would appreciate any improvements offered!!

```
function checkForYouTube($body,$androidid){
$searchArg = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v";
$pos = strpos($body,$searchArg);
if ($pos){
    $url = substr($body,$pos,100);
    $pos1 = strpos($url,"&");
    $url = substr($url,0, $pos1);
    $pos = strrpos($url,"=");
    $movieId = trim(substr($url,$pos+1));
    if (substr($movieId,0,2)=="3D")$movieId = substr($movieId,2);
    $url = $searchArg."=".$movieId;
    $comment = "(Movie=".$url.")".$comment;
    $inc = insertfamilypicture ($androidid,$comment,$url);
    sendYouTubeMovie($androidid, $movieId, $inc);
    return true;
}
return (false);
```

}

The return enable the email to be deleted.
It seems a rough-and-ready way to catch YouTube "Shares" for an Android user.

The use-case is an always-on tablet for a less computer-savvy senior which will make interesting YouTubes available from his family "Sharing" them from a smart phone or a youTube app.

Does anyone have a better way to identify an email carrying a YouTube url